# How to point to eng.traineddata in Tess4J OCR project

Tags: java, netbeans, tess4j

I am new in Tess4J. I'm getting this error

Error opening data file ./tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Empty page!!

After searching, I added environment variable TESSDATA_PREFIX pointing to "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata" which has eng.traineddata file.

How can I get this to work. Please help, step by step if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The datapath should be set to `"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\"`.

Answer (score 0):

First，you need to download the [language data file](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files).

Then,set the environment variable to point to your tessdata directory.

Ex:if your tessdata path is '/usr/local/share/tessdata'

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX='/usr/local/share/'
```

Finally,move the language data files to the tessdata directory:

```
sudo mv Downloads/eng.traineddata /usr/local/share/
```

now,try~

Comment: These instructions will not work for this exact question; you can see that the OP is using Windows from the question context, and therefore `export`, `sudo`, `mv`, and all the paths you mention will not exist. @nguyenq's answer is the correct answer to OP's question, but perhaps this answer should remain and be edited to clearly state it refers to a Linux environment?